# How to strengthen the keepass master password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, keepass

Is it safe to strengthen the master password and keep the same keepass database file?  Is there any residual trace of the old weaker password?

Alternatively, It looks like I can create a new database with the strong password and then import the old database directly from the kdbx file.  That should avoid any unencrypted residue files.

Overall I'm very happy with keepass's design.  I think this needs to be documented though.  This case is not addressed after I checking several of their docs, including the main "help" for "Change Master Key.." https://keepass.info/help/base/keys.html .. It is interesting that this is actually a concern for the LUKS full disk encryption.  It has to do with the protocol and the large volume of information it needs to manage.  That case is documented in LUKS though a way that anyone concerned will not miss it.

Comment: How do you mean to "strengthen the password"? Make it longer? And which LUKS documentation are you talking about, specifically? The passphrase processing time, or the main cipher & hash?